# MUI: Drawer Stays Open About 1 in 5 Times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I have a an MUI drawer that is supposed to close after a menu items is clicked, but about 1 out of 5 times it stays open. I've modeled my current code after [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72239170/how-do-i-link-to-another-page-in-my-mui-mini-drawer-sidebar/72251479#72251479).

Here is the code:

**NAVBAR COMPONENT**

```
const [hamburgerMenuIsOpen, setHamburgerMenuIsOpen] = useState(false);

function handleClickOnHamburgerMenu() {
    setHamburgerMenuIsOpen(true);
}

// [.....]


return(
    <>
        // MORE COMPONENTS
        <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="Menu"
            onClick={handleClickOnHamburgerMenu}
            key="hamburger_menu"
            size="large">
            <MenuIcon sx={classes.topNavBarIconMenu}/>
        </IconButton>

        <HamburgerMenu
            client={client}
            isOpen={hamburgerMenuIsOpen}
            setIsOpen={setHamburgerMenuIsOpen}
        />
    </>
)
```

**HAMBURGER MENU COMPONENT**

```
const {client, isOpen, setIsOpen} = props;

// [.....]

function closeMenu(e){
    setIsOpen(false);
    e.stopPropagation()
}

console.log('in hamburger_menu - about to redraw component. isOpen: ', isOpen)
return (
    (<>
        <Drawer
            open={isOpen}
            onClose={(e) => closeMenu(e)}
            anchor='right'
            key='navBarDrwr'
        >
            <List>
                <ListItem component={Link} to={""} button key={"Home"} onClick={(e) => closeMenu(e)}>
                    <ListItemText primary={"Home"}/>
                </ListItem>

                // [...MORE LIST ITEMS...]
                
            </List>
        </Drawer>
```

What seems particularly odd is that this line:

```
console.log('in hamburger_menu - about to redraw component. isOpen: ', isOpen)
```

...prints out:

> in hamburger_menu - about to redraw component. isOpen:  false

...but the drawer stays open anyway!

What am I missing?

Comment: try doing `<Drawer onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation()}}>`

Comment: The suggestion did not work.  Setting up a codesandbox...

Comment: I haven't been able to get the demo working on CodeSandBox or StackBlitz. I don't use those sites enough to know yet how to get react-router working. I keep getting these obscure error messages.

Comment: BUT I have noticed something new. My components are lazy-loaded, and the anomaly only appears when the component being linked to is being lazy-loaded for the first time. Does that ring a bell by any chance? Googling for this now...

Comment: I think I may have fixed this. There seems to be a race condition between React.lazy and mui. When a component is being lazy-loaded, mui seems to lose track of its drawer open state. To test this hypothesis, I used dynamic imports to make sure a component was loaded before I sent the client to that page in response to a menu click. So far it seems to have solved it. The trade-off is that instead of the drawer sticking open occasionally, there can be a slow page load occasionally while the component loads. If the anomaly doesn't recur in the next week or so I may put this up here as an answer.

Comment: It seems to be working so I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have fixed this. There seems to be a race condition between React.lazy and mui. When a component is being lazy-loaded, mui seems to lose track of its drawer open state.

To test this hypothesis, I used dynamic imports to make sure a component was loaded before I sent the client to that page in response to a menu click. So far it seems to have solved it. The trade-off is that instead of the drawer sticking open occasionally, there can be a slow page load occasionally while the component loads.

E.g.:

```
<MenuItem selected={pathname === '/faq'} onClick={() => handleHamburgerMenuClick('faq')}>FAQ</MenuItem>
```

...and in `function handleHamburgerMenuClick()`:

```
//select module to load
switch (target) {
    case 'faq':
        pathToGoTo = '/faq';
        moduleToLoad = "../docs/faq-stand-alone";
        break;
    [.....]
}

//dynamic import
import(moduleToLoad).then(module => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        history.push(pathToGoTo);
    }, 50);
})
closeHamburgerMenu();
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix was like this: when clicking an item to not do closeMenu() and navigate(path) in the same render. (you can put one of them in a setTimeout with a small time, but I didn't went like this.)

My solution was:
when clicking to navigate to the desired path (if the path is the current pathname just close the menu).
an effect listening for changes in the pathname that closes the drawer.

```
const location = useLocation();
const { pathname } = location;

useEffect(() => {
    closeMenu();
}, [pathname]);

const onSelectItem = (path: string) => {
  if (path === pathname) {
    closeMenu();
    return;
  }
  navigate(path);
};
```